# Took in a feral cat, but she is hiding and not eating

Tags: cats, behavior, fear, feral

I started to feed this feral cat, who would walk around my apartment building but I would only see her at night. She would wait for my boyfriend and I Outside our door,she would  come inside and eat as well.

We never touched her because she was very paranoid and scared, but few nights ago my boyfriend closed the door and she freaked out, ran around and hid in my closet. When I tried to calm her down or get close, she would hiss and show her teeth or just meow at me. The whole night she slept On the shoe rack and didn’t move. I left some food for her and a litter box  in the same room , but she didn’t use it.

In the morning I tried to touch her again, she let me but after a few minutes she then hissed again after that she got scared and urinated on the floor. She’s slowly been moving around the apartment hiding under dressers and behind things, but still won’t eat, won’t sleep on the blanket I gave her or even use the litter box.

And yes, I have opened the door for her and she won’t leave either or go out to the balcony. She’s just very scared and I understand she needs space to get used to us and comfortable, but I’m worried because she hasn’t used the bathroom or eaten!

Comment: Use the litter box is nothing a cat do of itself. There are a lot of questions about litter box training in here. I assume for the first time you need to make your home (or the room of the cat) pee and poo proof...

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17928/any-tips-for-how-to-coax-and-teach-a-shy-feral-cat-to-trust?r=SearchResults